# Eclipse RegExp Console Parsing Errors into Problems Window

Tags: regex, parsing, installation, eclipse-cdt, makefile

Eclipse expert help needed!  I have set up a makefile project to compile and link HCS12 code using the free codewarrior tools. It all seems to work well, but the only error/warning/information output I can get is to the console, with nothing being scanned from the console into the Problems window. I set up a regular expression error parser(Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Error Parsers) to scan the console for the appropriate information. If I search the console output (click in output and F) using find/replace with "regular expressions" checked, I find the warnings and errors--they just never get to the Problems tab.

I have enabled the error parser in (Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->ErrorParsers).

Somewhere I read that I need to enable this in C/C++ Makfile settings--but I cannot fine any settings which include the name "Makefile"; did I set up my project wrong??

Any suggestions or ideas on how to get my parsed errors into the problems window?

Eclipse Luna, Windows 7 professional.

Comment: As a newbie to the forum, I call two downgrades without a single comment regarding what is wrong with the question, nor any advice on where to go from here, a bit harsh.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Regex parser for Eclipse (at least the older version I am currently using) assumes you start at the beginning of a line of text and end at the end of a line of text.  My compiler errors were spanning multiple lines;  I found a switch in the compiler which allowed it to output the errors in "microsoft format", which was then on a single line.

the new warning line looks like
.\CODE\LIBCODE\CodeLibraries\Drivers\CI2C1.C(312): WARNING C1801: Implicit parameter declaration for 'CI2C1_OnMasterBlockSent'

regex that works is now
[^"\n]*\([^"(]*)((\d+)): WARNING C(\d+):([^\n]*)

of particular note is the [^"\n]*\ at the beginning of the regex expression, which matches all characters from the beginning of the line until the last \ is found--this is the piece I was missing.  Eclipse Kepler is rather unforgiving about the regex it requires.

and we have
File $1  (just the file name--eclipse adds the path mysteriously if the file is in a code directory of the project)

Line $2 (gathers the line number of the error)

Descrioption $4 ( I ignore WARNING and the warning number, and capture the description of the error to the end of the line)

I now have a useful and somewhat more modern IDE to work with ancient code which grew from the assembly code over many years and was never parsed out into libraries or restructured into modern levels of abstraction.